# SLIDER problema

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider

estoy queriendo hacer un slider y sigo los pasos pero no me sale el tema de  la función de las flechas que deberían pasar a la siguiente imagen, supongo debe ser un tema de JQUERY.

No me funciona ni siquiera los que incluyen CDN, no sé qué pasa.

Si pudieran pasarme el código de JQUERY para realizar tal función se los agradecería, supongo debe ser algo que incluya el "add Event Listener" pero no me salió.
Agrego captura de lo que muestra la consola.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les muestro el código que estoy probando ahora, a ver si hay algo mal.
Muchas Gracias.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('next').on('click', function(){
    
    var currentImg = $('.active');
    var nextImg = currentImg.next();

    if(nextImg.length){
      currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
      nextImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
    }
  });
    
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.clearfix{
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
#global{
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 25px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px gray;
}
.container{
    width: 540px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.slider-inner{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    border: #666 solid 1px;
}

.slider-inner img{
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
.slider-inner img.active{
    display: inline-block;
}

.prev,.next{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.prev{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 45px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        
        <!-- JQUERY Y CSS -->        
        <script type="text/javascipt" src="js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <script type="text/javascipt" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <title>Proyecto con Javascript</title>
               
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="global">
            <!--CABECERA PARTE SUPERIOR-->
            <header>
                <div id="logo">
                    <h1>PROYECTO JS</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </header>
            
            <!-- SLIDER -->
            <div class="container">
            
                <div class="slider-outer">
                    <a href="" class="prev" alt="prev">&#10094;</a>
                    <div class="slider-inner">
                        <img src="img/cielo.jpg" class="active">
                        <img src="img/hojas.jpg">
                        <img src="img/rojo.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="next" alt="next">&#10095;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
                
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sieria mejor que pusieras el por que no te funciona, poner un error de la consola, para así saber que esta fallando. Además donde esta la clase active? En css

Comment: El selector `$('next')` es incorrecto, porque jQuery va a buscar una etiqueta `<next>`. Si estás usando ID, debería ser `$('#next')` y, si es clase, entonces `$('.next')`

Comment: Hola @christian. Ahí puse una captura de la consola, eso es lo que muestra. La clase active, según un tutorial, la puse en  <img src="img/cielo.jpg" class="active"> en html y .slider-inner img.active{
    display: inline-block;
}  en JAVASCRIPT

Comment: Hola, @Triby gracias por el detalle de la clase. Igualmente sigue sin funcionar. Según dice en el tutorial  el "var nextImg = currentImg.next();" ese ".next();" sería una propiedad predefinida de jquery. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí funciona al especificar correctamente la clase y asegurar que se está cargando jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Selector por clase
  $('.next').on('click', function(){
    
    let currentImg = $('.active');
    let nextImg = currentImg.next();

    if(nextImg.length){
      currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
      nextImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
    }
  });
    
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.clearfix{
    float: none;
    clear: both;
}
#global{
    width: 65%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding: 25px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px gray;
}
.container{
    width: 540px;
    margin: 40px auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.slider-inner{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    border: #666 solid 1px;
}

.slider-inner img{
    display: none;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
.slider-inner img.active{
    display: inline-block;
}

.prev,.next{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.prev{
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 45px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="global">
            <!--CABECERA PARTE SUPERIOR-->
            <header>
                <div id="logo">
                    <h1>PROYECTO JS</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </header>
            
            <!-- SLIDER -->
            <div class="container">
            
                <div class="slider-outer">
                    <a href="" class="prev" alt="prev">&#10094;</a>
                    <div class="slider-inner">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525598912003-663126343e1f?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8cGhvbmV8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="active">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534536281715-e28d76689b4d?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTJ8fHBob25lfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584438784894-089d6a62b8fa?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8cGhvbmV8ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="next" alt="next">&#10095;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
                
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            
        </section>
```

Comment: Aiii Gracias!! lo probé y funciona. Hace tres días vengo con esto, ahora puedo continuar con el curso Gracias!!